# Python Class Instance member variable isn't being updated inside thread

Tags: python, multithreading

Currently creating separate instances of my class, Example, then creating a thread for each instance and utilizing the Class's execute_thread function as the thread function target. The thread function continues running as long as the member variable exit_signal is not updated to True. Once control, shift, and 2 are pressed on the keyboard, the member variable isn't updated from within the thread instance.

The problem is the thread function isn't recognizing any change to the member variable, why isn't it detecting the change, is the while loop preventing it from doing so?

```
import keyboard
import multiprocessing
import time


class Example:

    m_exit_signal = False

    def __init__(self):
        keyboard.add_hotkey('control, shift, 2', lambda: self.exit_signaled())

    def execute_example_thread(self):

        exit_status = self.m_exit_signal

        # THREAD continues till exit is called! -
        while exit_status == False:

            time.sleep(5)

            exit_status = self.m_exit_signal

            print(exit_status)

    def exit_signaled(self):
        self.m_exit_signal = True
        print("Status {0}".format(self.m_exit_signal))


example_objects = []
example_objects.append(Example())
example_objects.append(Example())
example_threads = []

for value in example_objects:
    example_threads.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=value.execute_example_thread, args=()))
    example_threads[-1].start()
```

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is our friend.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: True, though formatting seemed to have gone out the digital window when I pasted it here. Sorry man.

Comment: You are also missing some variables/functions.  The indenting just requires using the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Did you try to run the code you have here?  Because you can't, there are still things missing.

Comment: @StephenRauch that's because this was a conceptual example based off the very real issue that I'm having. Updated it to run as of this point.

Comment: If it can not run it is not MCVE.  If it is not MCVE then it is very hard to test.  If it is hard test, many will not be interested in helping you.

Comment: Python multiprocessing.Process() creates a copy of the the code and runs it in a separate process (so you actually have 2 local and 2 forked).  I suspect your variable is changing in the local version but not the one running in the forked processes.  In general, you need to create a shared Value or Queue (ie... multiprocessing.Value) in order to pass data back and forth.

Comment: I see, though with this implementation I'm not passing values to the thread, rather updating the instance's values from within the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing forks your code so that it runs in a separate process.  In the code above the keyboard callback is calling the method in the instances present in the parent process.  The loop (and a copy of the class instance) is actually running in a forked version in a child process.  In order to signal the child, you need to share a variable between them and use it to pass data back and forth.  Try the code below.

```
import keyboard
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, hot_key):
        self.run = mp.Value('I', 1)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('control, shift, %d' % hot_key, self.exit_signaled)
        print("Initialized {}".format(mp.current_process().name))

    def execute(self):
        while self.run.value:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Running {}".format(mp.current_process().name))
        print("{} stopping".format(mp.current_process().name))

    def exit_signaled(self):
        print("exit signaled from {}".format(mp.current_process().name))
        self.run.value = 0

p1 = mp.Process(target=Example(1).execute)
p1.start()
time.sleep(0.1)
p2 = mp.Process(target=Example(2).execute)
p2.start()
```

Here the parent and the child of each instance share an `self.run = mp.Value` To share data, you need to use one of these, not just any python variable.

Comment: thank you! would upvote but not enough score, though good work!